# How to use _e() inside php function?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

`<?php _e( 'text', 'textdomain'); ?>` is used to translate text in themes and plugins. But what if i have a php function that defines text as a variable:

```
$textoutput = 'blablabla';
```

In another document the variable is echoed:

```
echo $textoutput;
```

How to translate the 'blablabla' text?
`$textoutput = _e( 'blablabla', 'textdomain');` doesnt work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_e( 'blablabla', 'textdomain');` is used for echoing to the browser, not for assignment to a variable.

If you wish to assign it to a variable you need to use a different function which is `$variable = __( 'blablabla', 'textdomain')`

that means these code lines of code do the same thing

```
_e( 'blablabla', 'textdomain');
echo __( 'blablabla', 'textdomain');
$variable = __( 'blablabla', 'textdomain');
echo $variable;
```

More information on wordpress i18n can be found in the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)